# PHP check if value exists and return full row of the given value in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to check if a value exists and return the full row of the given value in a multidimensional array?

```
$userdb = Array
(
    (0) => Array
        (
          '100',
           'Sandra',
           'urlof100'
        ),

    (1) => Array
        (
            '5465',
            'Stefanie',
            'urlof5465'
        ),

    (2) => Array
        (
            '40489',
            'Michael',
            'urlof40489'
        )
);
```

eg. check if `Sandra` is in array.
yes `Sandra` is in array and the row is 0

```
(0) => Array
        (
             '100',
            'Sandra',
              'urlof100'
        )
```

**I get the first part:**

```
if (in_array("Sandra", array_column($userdb, 1))) {
    // echo "FOUND";
 }
```

but I can't understand how do I get the array to which Sandra belongs.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

The question of the OP bears an uncanny resemblance to a comment in the PHP Manual; see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#116635).  That said, you could solve the matter simply by coding as follows:

```
<?php
$userdb = [
        [
          '100',
           'Sandra',
           'urlof100'
        ],

        [  '5465',
            'Stefanie',
            'urlof5465'
        ],

        [   '40489',
            'Michael',
            'urlof40489'
        ]
];

function getRow($find,$db,$col){
  $key = array_search($find, array_column($db, $col));
  if ($key !== false) {
     echo "Yes, \"$find\" is in array in row $key\n";
  }
  return $db[$key];
}
$row = getRow('Sandra',$userdb,1);
print_r($row);
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/Y90XS)

The second parameter passed to array_column() is 1 because all the names are stored in column 1.  Once array_search() locates "Sandra" it returns the row number.

If you didn't know the column information, you could get both the row and column, as follows:

```
<?php
array_walk($userdb, function($e,$i) {
      if (in_array("Sandra",$e)) {
             $k = array_search('Sandra',$e);
             echo "Yes, \"Sandra\" is in array at row $i and column $k\n";
      }
});
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/tRME0#output)

Using [array_walk()](http://php.net/array_walk) can simplify the code, making it easier to grasp. Array_walk() applies a callback to every member of an array.

Lastly, you may use explicit iteration to obtain the row information, as follows:

```
<?php
foreach($userdb as $k => $v) {
    if (is_array($v) && in_array('Sandra',$v)) {
       echo "Yes, \"Sandra\" in array at row $k\n";
    }
}
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/562Fj#output)

Answer (score 0):

You have a multidimensional array. So you can use foreach loop to get the key. Like foreach($array as $key=>$val){
Check here for in array, if found echo $key
}
It should work.